# AngularJs Factory not updating value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a base factory that houses all my commom API call, then extend them to their respective resources, that will be called by my controller.

The problem I'm having is whenever I try to call `tableResource.getAll()` (see code bellow), it just goes and gets the BaseFactory URL and not the URL from the resource I created.

My code is as follows:

## BaseFactory.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app.myapp', []).factory('BaseFactory', BaseFactory);

    function BaseFactory(RequestService) {
        /**
        * @ngdoc property
        * @name _url
        * @summary The odata URL
        */
        let _url = "/odata/";

        /**
        * @ngdoc Method
        * @name _getAll
        * @summary Gets the full list of items        
        */
        let _getAll = () => {
            return RequestService.get(_url, {});
        }

        let service = {
            url: _url,
            getAll: _getAll
        }

        return function (options) { angular.extend(this, service, options) }
    }
})();
```

## TableResource.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app.myapp').service('tableResource', tableResource);

    function tableResource(BaseResource) {
        /**
        * @ngdoc function
        * @name init
        * @summary Initializes the resource by extending the base resource 
        */
        let init = () => {
            var base = new BaseResource({ url: '/odata/Table' });
            angular.extend(this, base);
        }

        init();

        return this;
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know too much about service inheritance in angularjs but it seems you are making resource request with base service url: `RequestService.get(_url, {});`.

And if I'm not wrong when you are creating the child service you are just setting `service.url`. You should use `service.url` inside `_getAll()` or add a setter method.